# If statement inside a for loop in Java

Tags: java

I'm new in Java and trying to do some trivial stuffs and exercises, I came with this bump though, I want the word "ducks" to be singular when the output reaches 1 or 0, here is my code:

```
public class FiveLittleDucks {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String word = "";

        System.out.println("The story of the 5 little ducks");
        for(int duck = 5 ; duck>0 ; duck--) {
            if(duck == 1 || duck == 0) {
                word = "duck";
            } else {
                word = "ducks";
            }
            System.out.printf("%d little %s went out one day, over the hills and far away, mother duck said quack, quack, quack, quack", duck, word);
            System.out.printf(" but only %d little %s went back\n", duck-1, word);
        }
    }
}
```

here is the output:
The story of the 5 little ducks

5 little ducks went out one day, over the hills and far away, mother duck said quack, quack, quack, quack but only 4 little ducks went back

4 little ducks went out one day, over the hills and far away, mother duck said quack, quack, quack, quack but only 3 little ducks went back

3 little ducks went out one day, over the hills and far away, mother duck said quack, quack, quack, quack but only 2 little ducks went back

2 little ducks went out one day, over the hills and far away, mother duck said quack, quack, quack, quack but only ***1 little ducks*** went back

1 little duck went out one day, over the hills and far away, mother duck said quack, quack, quack, quack but only 0 little duck went back

notice the "1 little ducks" is still in plural form whereas the bottom line is already in singular form.. thanks guys..

Comment: That's because you're outtputing `duck -1`, but tested `duck`. So. at ducks=2, you get the plural, but then output duck-1, which is the singular. Since you have TWO places where the duck count is output, and they have different values, you'll need TWO duck/ducks strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each iteration of the loop prints two lines - one with the current counter of `duck` and one with `duck-1`. However, you assign a value to `word` based on `duck`, so when `duck` is 2 the word is `"ducks"`, even though `duck-1` is 1. One way to solve this is to extract the calculation of the word from the loop and evaluate it individually:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("The story of the 5 little ducks");
    for(int duck = 5 ; duck>0 ; duck--) {
        System.out.printf("%d little %s went out one day, over the hills and far away, mother duck said quack, quack, quack, quack", duck, ducksToWord(duck));
        System.out.printf(" but only %d little %s went back\n", duck-1, ducksToWord(duck-1));
    }
}

private static String ducksToWord(int duck) {
    if (duck == 1 || duck == 0) {
        return "duck";
    } 
    return "ducks";
}
```

Comment: Wow! thanks man, that did it perfectly.. I was keeping it as compact and concise as possible that's why I didn't use the while loop like 99 bottles of beer exercise was using.. thanks again man..